# Transpose column to row into Formatted Output:

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Would like to transpose below Non formatted Input into Formatted Output, since it is having multiple de-limited,
got struck to proceed further and looking for your suggestions.

Sample_Input.txt

```
  UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    callForwarding                                              
      chargeableDuration                                            0  4 44'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        57526'D




UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    mSTerminating                                               
      chargeableDuration                                            0  4 44'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        57573'D
      originalCalledNumber                                        149212345678'TBCD
      redirectingNumber                                           149387654321'TBCD




!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1164!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    mSTerminating                                               
      chargeableDuration                                            0  0 52'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        45761'D
      tariffClass                                                 2'D
      timeForStartOfCharge                                          9 46 58'BCD
      calledSubscriberIMSI                                        21329701412F'TBCD
```

Searched in previous questions and got some relavent inputs from Mr.Porges Answer:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # split lines on " " and use "," for output field separator
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = " "; i = 0; h = 0; ofs = "," }

   # empty line - increment item count and skip it
   /^\s*$/ { i++ ; next } 

   # normal line - add the item to the object and the header to the header list
   # and keep track of first seen order of headers
   {
      current[i, $1] = $2
      if (!($1 in headers)) {headers_ordered[h++] = $1}
      headers[$1]
   }

   END {
      h--

      # print headers
      for (k = 0; k <= h; k++)
      {
         printf "%s", headers_ordered[k]
         if (k != h) {printf "%s", ofs}
      } 
      print "" 

      # print the items for each object
      for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      {
         for (k = 0; k <= h; k++)
         {
            printf "%s", current[j, headers_ordered[k]]
            if (k != h) {printf "%s", ofs}
         }
         print ""
      }
  }' Sample_Input.txt
```

Am getting below output:

```
UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord,callForwarding,chargeableDuration,dateForStartOfCharge,recordSequenceNumber,mSTerminating,originalCalledNumber,redirectingNumber,!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1164!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!,tariffClass,timeForStartOfCharge,calledSubscriberIMSI
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,0,09011B'H,57526'D,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,0,09011B'H,57573'D,,149212345678'TBCD,149387654321'TBCD,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
  ,,0,09011B'H,45761'D,,,,,2'D,9,21329701412F'TBCD
  ,,,,,,,,,,,
```

where it stucks,
(a). Need to tackle when the block starts like "UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord" and Empty Field , then the next line words like callForwarding/mSTerminating etc and Empty Field,
First word need to be considered as Row ("UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord" ) and next line word need to be considered as Column (callForwarding/mSTerminating)

(b). Need to avoid the ALPHAPET into column fields i.e 09011B'H into 09011 , 149212345678'TBCD into 149212345678

Expected Output:

```
UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord,chargeableDuration,dateForStartOfCharge,recordSequenceNumber,originalCalledNumber,redirectingNumber,tariffClass,timeForStartOfCharge,calledSubscriberIMSI
callForwarding,0  4 44,09011,57526,,,,,
mSTerminating,0  4 44,09011,57573,149212345678,149387654321,,,
mSTerminating,0  0 52, 09011,45761,,,2,9 46 58,21329701412
```

Edit:I have tried on the below Input:

```
  UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    callForwarding                                              
      chargeableDuration                                            0  4 44'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        57526'D




UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    mSTerminating                                               
      chargeableDuration                                            0  4 44'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        57573'D
      originalCalledNumber                                        149212345678'TBCD
      redirectingNumber                                           149387654321'TBCD




!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1164!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord                                   
    mSTerminating                                               
      chargeableDuration                                            0  0 52'BCD
      dateForStartOfCharge                                        09011B'H
      recordSequenceNumber                                        45761'D
      tariffClass                                                 2'D
      timeForStartOfCharge                                          9 46 58'BCD
      calledSubscriberIMSI                                        21329701412F'TBCD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Discussion

This is a complex problem since the records are non-uniform: some with missing fields. Since each record occupies several lines, we can deal with it using AWK's multi-records feature: by setting the `RS` (record separator) and `FS` (field separator) variables.

Next, we need to deal with collecting the header fields. I don't have a good way to do this, so I hard-code the header line.

Once we establish the order in the header, we need a way to extract a specific field from the record and we accomplish that via the function `get_column()`. This function also strip off non-numeric data at the end per your requirement.

One last thing, we need to trim the white spaces off the first column (`$2`) using the homemade `trim()` function.

## Command Line

I placed my code in `make_csv.awk`. To run it:

```
awk -f make_csv.awk Sample_Input.txt
```

## File make_csv.awk

```
BEGIN { 
    # Next two lines: each record is of multiple lines, each line is a
    # separate field
    RS = ""
    FS = "\n"
    print "UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord,chargeableDuration,dateForStartOfCharge,recordSequenceNumber,originalCalledNumber,redirectingNumber,tariffClass,timeForStartOfCharge,calledSubscriberIMSI"
}

function get_column(name, i, f, len) {
    # i, f and len are "local" variables
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        len = split($i, f, " ")
        if (f[1] == name) {
            result = f[2]
            for (i = 3; i <= len; i++) {
                result = result " " f[i]
            }

            # Remove the trailing non numeric data
            sub(/[a-zA-Z']+/, "", result) 
            return result
        }
    }
    return "" # get_column not found, return empty string
}

# Remove leading and trailing spaces
function trim(s) {
    sub(/[ \t]+$/, "", s)
    sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", s)
    return s
}

/UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord/ {
    print trim($2) \
        "," get_column("chargeableDuration") \
        "," get_column("dateForStartOfCharge") \
        "," get_column("recordSequenceNumber") \
        "," get_column("originalCalledNumber") \
        "," get_column("redirectingNumber") \
        "," get_column("tariffClass") \
        "," get_column("timeForStartOfCharge") \
        "," get_column("calledSubscriberIMSI") \
        ""
}
```

## Update

I tried out my AWK script against AVN's latest input and got the following output:

```
UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord,chargeableDuration,dateForStartOfCharge,recordSequenceNumber,originalCalledNumber,redirectingNumber,tariffClass,timeForStartOfCharge,calledSubscriberIMSI
callForwarding,0 4 44,09011,57526,,,,,
mSTerminating,0 4 44,09011,57573,149212345678,149387654321,,,
mSTerminating,0 0 52,09011,45761,,,2,9 46 58,21329701412
```

Comment: Thanks Hai Vu for your good support , i have tested your first code , awk -f make_csv.awk Sample_Input.txt and got output UMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord,chargeableDuration,dateForStartOfCharge,recordSequenceNumber,originalCalledNumber,redirectingNumber,tariffClass,timeForStartOfCharge,calledSubscriberIMSI
callForwarding,0 4 44,09011,57526,149212345678,149387654321,,,
mSTerminating,0 0 52,09011,45761,,,2,9 46 58,21329701412

Comment: second block details missing in the output: mSTerminating,0  4 44,09011,57573,149212345678,149387654321,,,

Comment: I have tested my code before posting and it produced the correct output. You probably tried my code on a different input, which contains something that throw my code off. If you can, please post that input file.

Comment: Hai Vu , i have pasted the input under EDIT

Comment: It seems that if there is a blank lines before first block , it is not working properly

Comment: Please see my update for output I got. I tried your latest data, even with blank lines before the first block and it still works. Why don't you re-copy my script and try again?